# SQlite bug saying table doesnt exist

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created an SQlite table to save users but i am getting an exception when trying to add a user:
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: users in "INSERT INTO users(lastName,age,firstName) VALUES (?,?,?)"

the database handler class:

> ```
> package com.example.as.Data;
> ```
>
> import android.content.ContentValues; import android.content.Context;
> import android.database.Cursor; import
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; import
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper; import android.util.Log;
>
> import com.example.as.Model.User; import com.example.as.util.Util;
>
> import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;
>
> public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
>
> ```
> //the name is the name of the database we will be creating
> public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
>     super(context, Util.DATABASE_NAME, null, Util.DATABASE_VERSION);
> }
>
>
>
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
>         String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Util.TABLE_NAME + "("
>                 + Util.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Util.lastName + " TEXT,"
>                 + Util.lastName + " TEXT," + Util.age + " TEXT" + ")";
>         db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);
> }
>
> //this is called when you upgrade your database
> @Override
> public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
>     String DROP_TABLE = String.valueOf("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS");
>     db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE, new String[]{Util.DATABASE_NAME});
>     onCreate(db);
> }
>
> //how to add to database
> public void addContact(User user){  //we will use the contact obj to get our shit from content class
>     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
>
>     //structure that allows us to create the items to be added to the database
>     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
>     values.put(Util.firstName, user.getFirstName()); //putting in our values
>     values.put(Util.lastName, user.getLastName());
>     values.put(Util.age, user.getAge());
>
>     //inserting the ContentValues into the table
>     db.insert(Util.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
>     Log.d("DBHandler", "addContact: " + "item added");
>     db.close();
> }
>
> //get a contact by using their id number   /*  public User getUser(int id){
>     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
>     Cursor cursor = db.query(Util.TABLE_NAME,new String[]{Util.KEY_ID,
>                     Util.firstName, Util.lastName, Util.age},
>             Util.KEY_ID + "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
>             null,null,null);
>
>     if (cursor!=null)
>         cursor.moveToFirst();  //start iterating through
>
>     //creating and populating the contact obj that we will return
>     User user = new User();
>     user.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
>     user.setFirstName(cursor.getString(1));  //these are row numbers
>     user.setLastName(cursor.getString(2));
>     //0 is the id row and 1 is the name row
>     user.setAge(cursor.getString(3));
>     return user;
> }*/
>
> //lets get all of the contacts
> public List<User> getAllContacts(){
>     List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
>
>     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
>
>     //SQL string to select all contacts
>     String selectAll = "SELECT * FROM " + Util.TABLE_NAME;
>     //rawquery built in method allows you to pass in raw sql code
>     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectAll,null);
>     //iterate through the data
>     if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
>         do {
>             User user = new User();
>             user.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
>             user.setFirstName(cursor.getString(1));
>             user.setLastName(cursor.getString(2));
>             user.setAge(cursor.getString(3));
>             //add the contact objects to the list
>             userList.add(user);
>         }while (cursor.moveToNext());
>     }
>     return userList;
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

the util class:

```
> package com.example.as.util;

public class Util {

    //database related items (write psf for the options to show up)
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; //every database needs to have a version
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "users_db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "users"; //we need a table name

    //column names
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String firstName = "firstName";
    public static final String lastName  = "lastName";
    public static final String age = "age";


}
```

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.as;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.as.Data.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.as.Model.User;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button addUserbtn;
    private EditText firstNametxt;
    private EditText lastNametxt;
    private EditText agetxt;
    private TextView userstxt;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseHandler db  = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);

         addUserbtn = findViewById(R.id.aduserbtn);
         firstNametxt= findViewById(R.id.FirstNametxt);
         lastNametxt=findViewById(R.id.lastNametxt);
         agetxt = findViewById(R.id.agetxt);
         userstxt = findViewById(R.id.userstxt);




        addUserbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String firstName  = firstNametxt.getText().toString();
                String lastName = lastNametxt.getText().toString();
                String age = agetxt.getText().toString();
                User user = new User();
                user.setFirstName(firstName);
                user.setLastName(lastName);
                user.setAge(age);
                db.addContact(user);
              //  List<User> userList =db.getAllContacts();   //adding all users to list
               // for (User us: userList
                 //    ) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity","onCreate" + user.getFirstName());
                //}

            }
        });
    }


    //changing to all Users Screen
    public void ChangeScenes(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, allUsers.class);
        startActivity(intent);          //now we use the intent we made before
    }







}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an issue in Create table Query Please check it and before Add Data check in "**App Inspector**" Is Your Table created or not?

if Table create. then You Need To upgrade Database Version.

**Your Create Table Query**

```
 String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Util.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + Util.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Util.lastName + " TEXT,"
            + Util.lastName + " TEXT," + Util.age + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);
```

**Try This One**

```
 String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Util.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + Util.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Util.firstName + " TEXT,"
            + Util.lastName + " TEXT," + Util.age + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);
```

You face this issue because you wrote the last name two times in create table query.

Comment: Database inspector is showing that my table is not being created but i dont understand why I dont see any problems with my create table query, is there any way to check whats wrong with it?

Comment: Try The above code i have get the issue and solve this

Comment: I have made that change and i have a new excpetion now:  E/SQLiteLog: (1) incomplete input in "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"